# How many combinations can I make?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recursion

let $n \gt 1$ be an integer, and consider $n$ people; $P_1, P_2,..., P_n$ let $A_n$ be the number of ways these $n$ people can be divided into groups, such that each group have either one or two people

determine $A_1, A_2, A_3$

So I have

$A_1 = 1$ way
$A_2 = 4$ way
$A_3 = 12$ way

But I am not sure if this is right... Can anyone confirm?

edit:

My way of getting this is

$A_1 = 1 $ because {P1} only has 1 way to sort

$A_2 = 4$ because {P1,P2} = {P1,P2},{P2,P1},{P1P2},{P2P1}

etc.

Comment: What are the $4$ ways that you found to divide $P_1$ and $P_2$ into groups?

Comment: The groups $\{P_1,P_2\}$ and $\{P_2,P_1\}$ are the same group: the order in which you list its members doesn’t change the identity of the group. There are actually just two ways to do it: you can put both people in one group, getting the group $\{P_1,P_2\}$, or you can put each person into a separate group, getting the two groups $\{P_1\}$ and $\{P_2\}$.

Comment: Here $A_n$ actually represent the number of ways the n people can be divided into groups. So $A_1$ represents division of people such that a group only include one person but not only P1 and similarly $A_2$ represents division of people such that a group only includes two person but not only $P_1$ and $P_2$ and .......

Comment: For a more general discussion, [please see this.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/964367/counting-the-number-of-different-ways-in-which-groups-of-one-or-two-can-be-forme)

Answer (score 0):

The only case that hasn’t been handled in the comments is $n=3$. If each group must have either one or two people, and you have three people altogether, there are two basic types of groupings: you can put each person into his own group, or you can have one group of two people and one singleton. The first possibility gives you the groups $\{P_1\},\{P_2\}$, and $\{P_3\}$. There are several ways to get a group of two and a singleton; can you see what they are?